# copying several segments of the same video avconv

Tags: copy, avconv

I am trying to copy several segments of one video file to a single output video file
I can do it for one segment only by using the following code:
    avconv -i  input.flv -ss 00:04:50 -t 00:04:00 -codec copy outputfile.flv
Is there any way to  do it with several segments?

Comment: Does it have to be in one line? Can't you for example run avconv multiple times and merge the resulting video files?